# Hibernate alters tables each time I start the Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Each time I start my spring boot application, hibernate is altering some fields across all of my tables. This alternation is happening only to **Timestamp** and Date types such as **LocalDate** or **LocalDateTime** but not to other fields such as int, String or other objects.
Hibernate is setting the datatype to **Timestamp** even though it already is defined as Timestamp.

*Using: Java 17, PostgreSQL 15.3, Spring Boot 3.1.1*

**Console**

```
Hibernate: alter table if exists public.users alter column deleted_at set data type timestamp(6)
Hibernate: alter table if exists public.users alter column updated_at set data type timestamp(6)
```

**Application.yml**

```
  datasource:
    url: ${DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ddltest}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME:postgres}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD:root}
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: public
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
    open-in-view: false
    generate-ddl: true
server:
  port: ${API_PORT:8080}
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/v1
```

**Entity Class**

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User{

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name = "deleted_at")
    private Timestamp deletedAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Timestamp updatedAt;
    
}
```

**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.vojvoda</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce-api</name>
    <description>ecommerce-api</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in your configuration, you defined `generate-ddl: true`. This allows JPA to alter the database schema according to your entity definition. In case your database is already initialized, you turn it to false.

Second, you can use `@Temporal` to define the precision of your date/datetime/timestamp value in the database. When you have only the precision of the date, then you can use `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` to define the precision for the database column. You could, for example, use the Java class with the corresponding precision.

```java
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date updatedAt;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
The generate-ddl, is not causing the problem and does not seem to have any effect wether I set true, false or remove it all together.

The second suggestion to define the fields as java.util.Date and mark them with @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) works for me, but date will of course not include  the time and is not suitable for my cases. I thank you again for answering and trying to help the community.

Comment: There are several types for TemporalTypes. Then use DateTime If you want to include the time.

Comment: There are three types in temporal in package jakarta.persistence TemporalType: DATE, TIME, TIMESTAMP but not DATETIME. DATE and TIME do not give me the desired result, as for TIMESTAMP, it alters the table as in the original problem.

Comment: Especially in the beginning of a project it can be useful to leave generate-ddl / ddl-auto on - so changes in the entities are updated in the database. There should be no changes applied to the DB, if no changes in the entities happened - most certainly not, when the table configuration stays exatly the same as before the "change". This is certainly an error, i always declared fields like this and didn't have the issue before SB 3.x. I think it's a hibernate bug...

Comment: Yes I think that it must be an hibernate bug as well.